# Cordova Plugin not working

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use the `Cordova` plugin: `cordova-plugin-filepath`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filepath

on an `Corodva` / `Ionic` (`Android`) application.

I'm trying to use it with the same code as on the above url, I mean:

```
window.FilePath.resolveNativePath('content://...', successCallback, errorCallback);
```

But I get:

```
  [11:36:22]  typescript: D:/ionic2/test-app/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 27
        Property 'FilePath' does not exist on type 'Window'.

  L26:  this._camera.getPicture( options ).then(( imageData ) => {
  L27:      this.cameraUrl = window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imageData);
  L28:      this.photoSelected = true;
```

Do I have to import `window` somehow?

I'm using this plugin to convert the path of a file from:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/...
```

to:

```
/storage/sdcard/...
```

This is my environment information:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Just in case, here I drop the code for: `home.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component( {
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    cameraData: string;
    photoTaken: boolean;
    cameraUrl: string;
    photoSelected: boolean;

    constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, private _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer, private _camera: Camera ) {
        this.photoTaken = false;
    }

    selectFromGallery() {
        var options = {
            sourceType: this._camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
        };
        this._camera.getPicture( options ).then(( imageData ) => {
            this.cameraUrl = window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imageData);
            this.photoSelected = true;
            this.photoTaken = false;
        }, ( err ) => {
            // Handle error
        });
    }

    openCamera() {
        var options = {
            sourceType: this._camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            correctOrientation: true
        };
        this._camera.getPicture( options ).then(( imageData ) => {
            this.cameraData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
            this.photoTaken = true;
            this.photoSelected = false;
        }, ( err ) => {
            // Handle error
        });
    }

}
```

Any idea on how to make this plugin work?

**[EDIT 1]**

I modified the source code in the following way:

```
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
...
constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        private _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer,
        private _camera: Camera,
        private filePath: FilePath
) {
    this.photoTaken = false;
}
...
selectFromGallery() {
    var options = {
        sourceType: this._camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
    };
    this._camera.getPicture( options ).then(( imagePath ) => {
        this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath).then(filePath => {
            this.cameraUrl = filePath;
            this.photoSelected = true;
            this.photoTaken = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Also did:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for FilePath! Error at g (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133) at injectionError (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:1511:86) at noProviderError (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:1549:12) at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3051:19) at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3090:25) at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3022:25) at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:2891:21) at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3856:52) at resolveDep (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:11260:45) at createClass (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:11128:32) at createDirectiveInstance (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:10954:37) at createViewNodes (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:12303:49) at createRootView (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:12208:5) at callWithDebugContext (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:13339:42) at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:12800:12)
Stack
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for FilePath!
Error
    at g (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133)
    at injectionError (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:1511:86)
    at noProviderError (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:1549:12)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3051:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3090:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3022:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:2891:21)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:3856:52)
    at resolveDep (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:11260:45)
    at createClass (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:11128:32)
    at createDirectiveInstance (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:10954:37)
    at createViewNodes (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:12303:49)
    at createRootView (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:12208:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:13339:42)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:12800:12)
    at g (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133)
    at l (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6251)
    at http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6805
    at t.invokeTask (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15213)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/main.js:4415:37)
    at t.invokeTask (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15134)
    at n.runTask (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10390)
    at a (http://192.168.1.202:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:5313)
```

**[EDIT 2]**

Ont top of `[EDIT 1]` I did the following edition:

```
@Component( {
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [ FilePath ]
})
```

I'm not getting errors this time but the image is not loading. I used a text area to see the what `src` value is passed to the image.

I also noticed that now I'm getting the real path (that's good).

Maybe now is a matter of permissions of the embedded `webview`. Please, check this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-local-image-showing-in-view-on-device/30647

I think I'm getting closer.

Here is an `screenshot` of my phone:

[image]

**[EDIT 3]**

I'm `running` on a real `Android` device with this commnad:

```
$ ionic run android -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should follow the usage method in the Ionic2 doc, instead of the one in plugin doc.

Check the Ionic2 Doc here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/

First import the `FilePath`

```
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
```

Secondly add `FilePath` to your constructor

```
constructor( 
  public navCtrl: NavController, 
  private _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer, 
  private _camera: Camera,
  private filePath: FilePath
) {
    this.photoTaken = false;
}
```

Then use it like this in your code:

```
selectFromGallery() {
    var options = {
        sourceType: this._camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
    };
    this._camera.getPicture( options ).then(( imageData ) => {
        //use this.filePath instead of window.FilePath
        this.cameraUrl = this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imageData); 
        this.photoSelected = true;
        this.photoTaken = false;
    }, ( err ) => {
        // Handle error
    });
}
```

Edit: since the poster is using Ionic 3.0.1 a provider need to be added else will result in `no provider FilePath` error.

Add the provider inside @Component like so:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ FilePath ],
 ...
})
```

Hope this helps! ^_^

Comment: thanks, I think I'm getting closer but still not working. I did an edition: `[EDIT 1]` on my post. Could you check it out?

Comment: Since you are using Ionic 3.0.1 you need to add providers inside @Component like this.

    ```@Component({
      ...
      providers: [ FilePath ],
     ...
    })```

Comment: Getting closer, but not working yet. I did another edition: `[EDIT 2]`.

Comment: Are you running on real device or ionic serve? On browser it can't be displayed.

Comment: I'm running on a real Android device with this commnad: `$ ionic run android -l`. I just added a note with this info. Maybe the problem is that I have to grant access the webview to display local device images?, something similar to what is on this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-local-image-showing-in-view-on-device/30647? With webview I mean the underlying webview of Ionic/Cordva system.

Comment: This image path does not work with livereload. If you just ```ionic run android``` without ```-l``` it will work perfectly.

Comment: Niz, you are totally right, I removed the live reload parameter `-l` and it worked perfectly. Do you know why this functionality doesn't work with live reload?. Is there any way to make this work with live reload?. Thanks!

Comment: Currently there is no way to make it work with livereload because when you run livereload it's using the browser connection on the device this way it cannot read native path locations.